# How to invoke the onChildClick method of setOnChildClickListener programmatically?

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview, onclicklistener, expandablelistadapter

I'm a building an expandable listview.

Once the user makes a selection on a child item it redirects to a webview. When the user returns to the listview page, I want to retain the selection.

Here is the code i'm using:

```
final ExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, groupList, laptopCollection);
expListView.setAdapter(expListAdapter);

expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() 
{
     public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) 
     {

         final String selected = (String) expListAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

         LinearLayout llChildItem = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.llChildItem);
         llChildItem.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.nav_selected);

         Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyWebView.class);
         intent.putExtra("url","http://www.google.com");
         intent.putExtra("groupPosition", groupPosition);
         intent.putExtra("childPosition", childPosition);
         startActivity(intent);

         return true;
     }
});
```

I'm passing the `groupPosition` & `childPosition` through Intent. Is there some way that I can call the `onChildClick` method programmatically and also pass these two parameters, so as to maintain the selection that was made ?

Comment: check out performClick() and performItemClick();

Comment: @ElDuderino does performItemClick() work on expandable listview? Could u pls share me a link of a working example - Thanks

Comment: listView.setOnItemClickListener( .... ); listView.performItemClick(listView.getChildAt(position), position, listView.getItemIdAtPosition(position))... that should be it.

Comment: position - refers to the childPosition or groupPosition ?

Comment: I'd say group position, but maybe you have to play around a bit with listView.getExpandableListPosition(flatListPosition), getPackedPositionType(), getPackedPositionGroup(), getPackedPositionChild();

Answer (score 0):

You may use `startActivityForResult(intent,200);` instead of `startActivity(intent);`
to start webview.And from webview activity you can send those parameters back to the selection activity as

```
 Intent data = new Intent();
           intent.putExtra("groupPosition", groupPosition);
             intent.putExtra("childPosition", childPosition);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
```

and in selection activity you can use those parameters as

```
string groupPosition ,childPosition ; //activity global parameters


@Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

             if (requestCode == 200 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    groupPosition = data.getStringExtra("groupPosition");
    childPosition = data.getStringExtra("childPosition");
    }
    }
```

Based on those parameters you can make selection.

And override your onChildClick method as

// Listview on child click listener

```
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks. But how to invoke the onChildClick method programatically? Right now it gets invoked on user interaction.

Comment: override onChildClick method